# Django RAW SQL query how to pass date comparison

Tags: django

I am working with Django Raw SQL as I want to build a relatively complex query,

As part of it, I have a case statement that says 'if the date on the record is < today then 1 else 0 - this works.

```
overdue_phases = task.objects.filter(orgid=orgid, taskid=taskidx).raw('''
    
     SELECT '1' as id, case when research_due < "2022-12-01" AND research_status != "done" then 1 else 0 end as count     
     from app_task where taskid = "''' + taskidx + '''"''')
                   
overdue_phases = task.objects.filter(orgid=orgid, taskid=taskidx).raw('''

 SELECT '1' as id, case when research_due < "2022-12-01" AND research_status != "done" then 1 else 0 end as count     
 from app_task where taskid = "''' + taskidx + '''"''')
```

However, when I want to swap the hard coded date for TODAY() I can't make it work. I have tried passing a python date variable into the script (td = datetime.date.today()), but it doesn't return the right results!

Can anyone advise me please?

Comment: What do you mean "I can't make it work"? What is the exact code with this change? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Side note: Generally, you should not build a query by concatenating strings. This often can leave security flaws which allow someone to do a sql injection attack. There are techniques that can avoid this and I encourage you to learn how to build queries that are safe from sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this. You can use [*condition expressions* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Q, Value, When

overdue_phases = task.objects.filter(orgid=orgid, taskid=taskidx).annotate(
    count=Case(
        When(
            ~Q(research_status='done'),
            research_due__lt='2022-12-01',
            then=Value(1),
        ),
        default=Value(0),
    )
)
```

Or if a boolean is sufficient as well:

```
from django.db.models import Q

overdue_phases = task.objects.filter(orgid=orgid, taskid=taskidx).annotate(
    count=~Q(research_status='done') & Q(research_due__lt='2012-12-01')
)
```

or for older versions of Django with an [**`ExpressionWrapper`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

overdue_phases = task.objects.filter(orgid=orgid, taskid=taskidx).annotate(
    count=ExpressionWrapper(
        ~Q(research_status='done') & Q(research_due__lt='2012-12-01'),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

You can replace `'2022-12-01'` with `date.today()`.